# how to change view in ios tabbed application without changing tab and maintaining tab bar visible

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

i have an iphone project that is a tabbed application. 
In the first tab I have a login form and I want that the user data returned by the login funcion to be shown in another view that takes the place of the view that contains the login form, without changing tab, and without taking all window's space because I don't want the tab bar to be hidden.
How can I do this (without storyboard)?

```
CMAnagrViewController *reg = [[CMAnagrViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CMAnagrViewController" bundle:nil];

UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
    return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
}] lastObject];

//topWindow.rootViewController = reg;
[topWindow addSubview:reg.view];
```

if I do like this the view is too high and part of the navigation bar goes under the status bar and part of the tab bar is out of the screen, but if i uncomment the

```
//topWindow.rootViewController = reg;
```

line then the new window goes full screen and i see all the navigation bar under the status bar but there's no tab bar..

Thank you all!

Comment: what about dynamically change the controllers associated too your tab view controller in order to change the current one ? another way would to use a contained view controller and replace this one

Comment: i solved using UINavigationController and pushing the second view with animated:YES but thanks anyway